# How to recreate this date scroller in Kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

[image: Date chooser]

How would I go about creating the above date and time selector but in Kivy? I'd like the user to be able to select a date (by scrolling horizontally, I assume the Spinner would be good here?) and then a list of available times will appear below that they can select. For the time selection part I think I know how to do this, I'd just dynamically create radio buttons with a Label next to them from a list of available times.

Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be using MDDatePicker from KivyMD at https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/pickers/index.html#mddatepicker and once you select the date you can use a Bottom Sheet from here https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-sheet/index.html with the list of times>

Comment: Thanks, will the List Bottom Sheet be OK with ~ 17 different selection options?

Comment: Yes List Bottom Sheets are scrollable you can see https://youtu.be/4ezaBwM2I3o?t=521